# Dropbox API with Django - Authentication

Tags: python, django, dropbox-api

I'm trying to learn Dropbox API and want to use OAuth 2 for authorization. I'm getting following error:

```
dropbox_auth_start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Here is my code:

Views.py

```
from dropbox import DropboxOAuth2Flow
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def get_dropbox_auth_flow(web_app_session):
    redirect_uri = "https://www.my-dummy-url.com"
    APP_KEY = 'my-app-key'
    APP_SECRET = 'my-app-secret'
    return DropboxOAuth2Flow(
        APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, redirect_uri, web_app_session, "dropbox-auth-csrf-token")

def dropbox_auth_start(web_app_session, request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        authorize_url = get_dropbox_auth_flow(web_app_session).start()
        return redirect(authorize_url)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dropbox/', views.dropbox_auth_start, name='dropbox')
]
```

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Python-DropboxOAuth2Flow-Error-WSGIRequest-object-does-not/m-p/262650#M15330 ]

Answer (score 2):

An aside... as [@at14](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5557703/at14) said, request object needs to be the first argument. The first argument **is** the request object (in this case, `web_app_session` is the request object). The second argument called 'request' (in the `dropbox_auth_start` function) is not needed.

More to the point, session object needs to be called on the request object like so: web_app_session.session

```
def dropbox_auth_start(web_app_session):
    authorize_url = get_dropbox_auth_flow(web_app_session.session).start()
    return redirect(authorize_url)
```

Essentially, `web_app_session == request`, so adding the `if` block, you'd get:

```
def dropbox_auth_start(web_app_session):
    if web_app_session.method == 'GET':
        authorize_url = get_dropbox_auth_flow(web_app_session.session).start()
        return redirect(authorize_url)
```

Of course, `web_app_session` can be switched with `request`.

Answer (score 1):

request object needs to be the first argument to your function

```
def dropbox_auth_start(request, web_app_session):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        authorize_url = get_dropbox_auth_flow(web_app_session).start()
        return redirect(authorize_url)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did and now its complaining that:   dropbox_auth_start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'web_app_session'

Comment: Yep, what's web_app_session ? Who is going to pass it? If you add it as an argument in a view it needs to be passed through the URL